# By using servlet I'm trying to inserting the values in Mysql but it storing null values

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

```
import com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest;    
import java.io.File;    
import java.io.FileInputStream;    
import java.io.FileOutputStream;    
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.io.PrintWriter;    
import java.sql.DriverManager;    
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.Enumeration;    
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;    
import javax.servlet.ServletException;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class upload extends HttpServlet {

   File file2 = null;    
   long size=0;    
   String filePath="";    
   String paramname=null;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");    
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();    
        String s1=request.getParameter("fname");
        String s2=request.getParameter("lname");
        String s3=request.getParameter("mobile");
        String s4=request.getParameter("email");
        String s5=request.getParameter("date");
        String s6=request.getParameter("qual");
        String s7=request.getParameter("address");
        String s8=request.getParameter("year");
        String s9=request.getParameter("past");
        String s10=request.getParameter("max");
        String s11=request.getParameter("work");
        String s12=request.getParameter("instal");
        String s13=request.getParameter("adhar");
        String s14=request.getParameter("pan");

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    String dirName =context.getRealPath("\\");
    MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(request, dirName, 10 * 1024 * 1024);
    int f = 0;
    Enumeration files = multi.getFileNames();   
    while (files.hasMoreElements()) 
    {
        paramname = (String) files.nextElement();
        if(paramname.equals("d1"))
        {         
            paramname = null;
        }
                if(paramname != null && paramname.equals("file"))
        {

            f = 1;
                        filePath = multi.getFilesystemName(paramname);
                      if(filePath == multi.getFilesystemName(paramname)){
                           System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+filePath);

                        //filePath= userid+".jpg";
                       }
            String fPath = dirName+filePath;                            
                        file2 = new File(fPath);
                        size=file2.length();
                       System.out.println(fPath);                         
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file2);
            list.add(fs);

         FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("F:/artizen/images"              + filePath));
                         int j=0;
                         while((j=fs.read())!=-1){
                         fout.write((byte)j);
                         }
                         fs.close();
                         fout.close();

                }           
try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            java.sql.Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/artizen","root","");
            java.sql.PreparedStatement st=cn.prepareStatement("insert into painters(fname,lname,mobile,email,date,qual,address,year,past,max,work,instal,adhar,pan,photo) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            st.setString(1,s1);
            st.setString(2,s2);
            st.setString(3,s3);
            st.setString(4,s4);
            st.setString(5,s5);
            st.setString(6,s6);
            st.setString(7,s7);
            st.setString(8,s8);
            st.setString(9,s9);
            st.setString(10,s10);
            st.setString(11,s11);
            st.setString(12,s12);
            st.setString(13,s13);
            st.setString(14,s14);
            st.setString(15,filePath);

           int i=st.executeUpdate();
            if(i==1)
            {                    
                out.println("VALUES ARE INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY");
               out.println("<align=\"center\"><a href=\"inventory.jsp\">GO BACK TO MAIN PAGE</a>"); 
            }

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                out.println(e);
            }                        
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the values from page come not null? Have you checked them in debugger?

Comment: You need to try and narrow down the problem before posting a question on StackOverflow. For example, try printing out the values just before inserting them in the database to show that the values are not input null. Remove any code that does not demonstrate the problem.

Comment: If you have a multipart request, then there is a problem with parameters, you should check "How to get parameters when multipart request in JSP".